# Writing // instead of } in VS2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

my VS2013 writes `//` when I press `Alt Gr + '}'`. It is probably caused by an extension but I really don't know which one (or maybe it is something else).

How do I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]1)go to Tools->Enviorment->Keyboard

2)choose any command

3)you will have a textbox under "Press Shortcut Keys" label press the shortcut there

4)you will see comobobox shortcut used by with all programs that use it

5)now just find and disable